# How can I delete data from database after 1 hour?

Tags: django

Hi guys I have saved a user ip address in my database using django but I want to delete this ip address after one hour. Please tell me how can I do this in django.

My table name is `iptable`. In my ip table 2 columns - 1 is `ip_adress` and 2 is `date_time` of saved data. How can I delete this from my database after one hour please tell me.

Thanks in advance. If you need any information about my code please tell me, I will provide it on my comment section.

Comment: use Celery lib for this

Comment: con you explain me in brif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned in the comment this kind of task should be performed with scheduler. You can use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for that or use simpler library like [Django-Apscheduler](https://github.com/jarekwg/django-apscheduler) that does not require installing message queue server.

Very simplified example using django-apscheduler:

```py
# tasks.py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import DjangoJobStore, register_events, register_job

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), "default")

@register_job(scheduler, "interval", seconds=3600)
def delete_ip():
    for record in IpTable.objects.all()
        # I assumed here that date_time is time when your object was created
        time_elapsed = datetime.now() - record.date_time
        if time_elapsed > timedelta(hours=1):
           record.delete()

register_events(scheduler)
```

In your `urls.py` file you can than start your scheduler:

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

# import module with your task
from yourapp.tasks import scheduler

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
scheduler.start()
```

Comment: please tell me how can i do that

Comment: You can create task which will be executed every 60 minutes and iterate through all records in your table checking if time elapsed since record creation is greater than 60 minutes.

Comment: sir how i run this view function in every 60 minutes please tell me if my function is `def delete_ip:`

Comment: @xbound this line - `for record in IpTable.query.all()` is a horror

Comment: @Chiefir I know, that's why I said that it is very simplified solution. Maybe using `post_save` signal and registering deleting task for every record would be better approach.

Comment: sir i am use your code it work 100% in local host but i run it at pythonanywhere.com hosting then it give me error `The scheduler seems to be running under uWSGI, but threads have been disabled. You must run uWSGI with the --enable-threads option for the scheduler to work.` please tell me how can use this scheduler in pythonanywhere.com

Comment: I'm not familiar with pythonanywhere service but after reading [some information](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/13193/) surrounding topic of running asynchronous tasks it seems it's not really possible with your configuration of uWSGI server. Maybe you have free account thus you are not allowed to execute  scheduled tasks?